# Add row to grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to programmatically add a row to a GridView in C# ASP?

If yes, how ?

I want to add static data directly from the code, not from an array nor an datasource

Comment: I believe that you can, although I don't know if it is dynamically updated in any ASP page. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean like a footer? I think there's a footer template for doing this.

Comment: [You can](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16089/NewRow-GridView), but it's much more complicated than just using a datasource (f.e. a `DataTable`). With a datasource it's also easier to use paging, sorting or editing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

You can then bind your `GridView` to the `DataTable`...

```
gv.DataSource = dt;
gv.DataBind();
```

Comment: You might need to create columns for DataTable before creating your row. `dt.Columns.Add("Column1");`

Answer (score 5):

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "column1";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "column2";

string[] row1 = new string[] { "column1 value", "column2 value" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
```

Comment: This works fine in Windows Forms DataGridView, not in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

[GridViewRowsCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have `.Add` method, so you can't do it directly to the GridView.

There're alternatives. For example if you bind it to a DataTable - you can add custom row with data to the DataTable.

Another alternative - do it on client by adding a row to rendered HTML Table.

Comment: This looks like just the trick. Create a GridViewRow and append it to the grid view?

Answer (score 0):

Rows can be inserted on `GridView_RowCreated`, Like

```
protected void gvItems_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{                    
    GridViewRow NewHeader = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
    NewHeader.Font.Bold = true;
    NewHeader.CssClass = "heading";

    //Item#
    TableCell NewHeaderCell = new TableCell();
    NewHeaderCell.Text = "#";
    NewHeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
    NewHeader.Cells.Add(NewHeaderCell);

    //Item#
    NewHeaderCell = new TableCell();
    NewHeaderCell.Text = "Item#";
    NewHeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
    NewHeader.Cells.Add(NewHeaderCell);

    //Amount
    NewHeaderCell = new TableCell();
    NewHeaderCell.Text = "Amount";
    NewHeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
    NewHeader.Cells.Add(NewHeaderCell);
    GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + 
        rowIndex, NewHeader);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I still recommend that you use binding/datasource, but of course you don't have to. The following should do what you want:

```
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columntype = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        columntype.HeaderText = "Type";
        columntype.Width = 80;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(columntype);
```