# Populating Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

I'm currently working on `asp.net webforms` project and i have a page with

- `asp:textbox`
- `asp:DropDownList`
- `asp:linkbutton`

I also have an `asp:gridview` on the same page, and i need to insert a new row on it whenever i clicked a `linkbutton` **without saving the data into a `DataBase`**.
The way i used to achieve that is to save the data on a `ViewState` list.

So, my question is: Isn't there a better way to do that ? **if yes**, please show it in details.

**Update: I must not lose the gridview data when `PostBack` happens.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add row to grid view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257451/add-row-to-grid-view)

Comment: @VDWWD Please check out the updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [ASP .NET State Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) and there are several ways of dealing with it:

- View state
- Control state
- Hidden fields
- Cookies
- Query strings
- Application state
- Session state
- Profile Properties

Since you didnt provide more information i would suggest you to use Session state to save the data since it's the easiest way of doing it because the information is going to be stored on the server side where it belongs (Instead of wrongly using ViewState where the information is going twice to the client, one in de GridView.DataBind() and one more in the ViewState). You need to do something like this:

```
MyGridView.Datasource = (List<Object>)Session["myGridViewData"];
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

Whenever you insert/delete/modify a new row you must update the dataset in your myGridViewData Session variable.

And remember to refresh GridView.DataSource on every postback so you dont loose the information:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  grid1.DataSource = getDataSet();
  grid1.DataBind();      
}

private List<Object> getDataSet()
{
    if (Session["myGridViewData"] == null)
        Session["myGridViewData"] = new List<employee>();            

    return (List<Object>)Session["myGridViewData"];
}

protected void addNewRowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Object> list = (List<Object>)Session["myGridViewData"];       
    list.Add(new Object ());
    Session["myGridViewData"] = list;
}
```

Keep in mind **that is not a good practice** to update controls on Page_Load event, you should instead handle which of your postbacks refreshes the data and refresh the grid on the apropiate methods (page first loads, and add/modify/delete row).

If you are using .NET Framework 4.5 or superior i will advise you to use GridView model binding (SelectMethod)
[GridView Model Binding](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2013/03/SelectMethod-in-asp-net-45-Model-binding.html) With this is not necesary to refresh the DataSource on every postback explicitly in the Page_Load method which is a cleaner way of doing this.

EDIT: From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972427.aspx)

> Session State or ViewState?
>
> There are certain cases where holding a state value in ViewState is
>   not the best option. The most commonly used alternative is Session
>   state, which is generally better suited for:
>
> - Large amounts of data. Since ViewState increases the size of both the page sent to the browser (the HTML payload) and the size of form
>     posted back, it's a poor choice for storing large amounts of data.
> - Secure data that is not already displayed in the UI. While the ViewState data is encoded and may optionally be encrypted, your data
>     is most secure if it is never sent to the client. So, Session state is
>     a more secure option. (Storing the data in the database is even more
>     secure due to the additional database credentials. You can add SSL for
>     even better link security.) But if you've displayed the private data
>     in the UI, presumably you're already comfortable with the security of
>     the link itself. In this case, it is no less secure to put the same
>     value into ViewState as well.
> - Objects not readily serialized into ViewState, for example, DataSet. The ViewState serializer is optimized for a small set of
>     common object types, listed below. Other types that are serializable
>     may be persisted in ViewState, but are slower and generate a very
>     large ViewState footprint.

Comment: Mr.DiegoS , What state management would you recommend in case i need to keep my data on a Page-Level, and why ?

Comment: It depends on the data, i would tend to say you should use Session (which is the answer in most cases) but there are cases where you can use hidden fields (if the data amount is small) or even the database.

Comment: The data would be .. lets say a grid of 10 columns with maximum 50 rows.

Comment: i don't won't to keep my data across multiple pages, so the Session wouldn't be much useful.

Comment: But, the user might not have to save the data, he can easily press "cancel" . So, in that case, i have to remove these data from the database(Which is unnecessary ).

Comment: In that case use either SessionState or ViewState they both practically the same. Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx to learn about storing data in ViewState

Comment: @ZEZOmaster I added a brief explanation of when to use viewstate and when to use session !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131839/discussion-between-zezomaster-and-diegos).